# PHPUnit Listener loaded but unused

Tags: phpunit, listener

I'm using PHPUnit 3.4.14 and I'm trying to add a Listener.

I wrote a simple one:

```
class My_Test_Listener implements PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener
{
    public function addError(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time)
    {
...
```

I declared it in my phpunit.xml file:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="auth">
            <directory>./library/Ademe/Auth</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <listeners>
        <listener class="Listener" file="./library/My/Test/Listener.php">
    </listener>
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

My class is loaded (if I omit to implement one of the method, it says so in the logs), but I never go inside thoses methods.  I tried this for instance :

```
public function startTestSuite(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite)
{
    die('startTestSuite');
}
```

Do you have any idea of what could be missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK I got it, the class name was wrong, allthough no error was reported. I should have done this instead:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="auth">
            <directory>./library/Ademe/Auth</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <listeners>
        <listener class="My_Test_Listener" file="./library/My/Test/Listener.php">
    </listener>
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: I've got the same problem, thanks! You should accept your answer!

Comment: I had sort of the same issue, I needed to add the full namespace.

Comment: I wish it threw an error when the class was not found.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error but the listener worked only when I used

```
<listener class="\Name\Space\MyTestListeners" ></listener>
```

Comment: I prefer this because it's much more cleaner and follows PSRs.

This relies on composer autoloader (being eventually included through bootstrap).